# Not able to apply for a job

Tags: bug, stack-overflow-jobs

I'm not able to apply for this job https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/121524/senior-software-engineer-backend-shopback. When I click on the **apply now** button, it doesn't show anything. I have tried this in Firefox 49.0 and Google Chrome 53.0.2785.143 on Ubuntu 14.04.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE:**

Following errors are shown in the console:-

[image]

However, it works fine when accessed via HTTPS protocol, https://stackoverflow.com/jobs

Comment: Do you see any errors on the developer console? if you do, please add a screenshot to your question

Comment: Are you under a corporate network? It seems like there's a proxy removing the CORS headers (it also explains why HTTPS works)

Comment: Could be, I've seen my ISP embedding advertisements

Answer (score -1):

It may be some extension that's causing issues for you (assuming you have similar extensions installed in both browsers). Try opening an incognito window (Ctrl+Shift+N on Chrome) and trying it, this will disable all your custom settings and extensions. Worth a shot at least.

Comment: Still not working